# Eclipse Junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I just tried using JUnit test on Eclipse and I'm stuck with switching between the JUnit test and the main method.

The class has a main method, but whenever I run it, it runs the JUnit test cases, not the main method.

How can I run the main method again?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: Right click the Java file you want to run. Select "Run As"

Comment: It doesn't show me my program in the list

Comment: Which list? The Run As list should show either "JUnit test" or "Java Application". Your program is determined by the Java file you've clicked

Comment: It doesn't give me the option I'll put a screen shot down in this page

Comment: Please delete your answer below. You are allowed to [edit] the question

Comment: I think you need to first fix the Red X on the other file. You project cannot compile

Comment: As you can see I have fixed the red x but it doesn't give me the option to run it on java. should I post my code?

Comment: Maybe... You could also try to see if you can open "Run configurations" and run what you want from there. Your recents runs should be saved already

Comment: as you can see in the picture my class name is NHLStats but it only show me jUnit

Comment: Not too sure what to say. I just made a blank project with one Java file, added a JUnit test, then I get two "Run as" options.

Comment: I got it solved thanks for your help

Comment: Cool. You are welcome to provide the process you followed to fix it as an answer below